# Unable to connect my RDS SQL Server DB. Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10060

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-web-services

I am getting below error while trying to connect my instance.

> An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10060)`

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A basic Google search provides information about this problem and how to resolve it, both from MS and from existing SO posts, using the search phrase * Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10060*. Please make a basic effort to find a solution yourself before posting here.

Comment: You need to configure security groups to allow your current IP address to connect incoming. There must be a detailed guide somewhere that I can't find right now but here's a start: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html (see VPC Security Groups)

Answer (score 0):

To configure SQL Server 2005 to allow remote connections, you must complete these steps:

1. Enable remote connections on the instance of SQL Server that you
   want to connect to from a remote computer.
2. List item Turn on the SQL Server Browser service.

Configure the firewall to allow network traffic that is related to SQL Server and to the SQL Server Browser service.

You have to enable remote connections for each instance of SQL Server 2005 that you want to connect to from a remote computer. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Click Start, point to Programs, point to Microsoft SQL Server 2005, point to Configuration Tools, and then click SQL Server Surface Area Configuration.
2. On the SQL Server 2005 Surface Area Configuration page, click Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections.
3. On the Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections page, expand Database Engine, click Remote Connections, click Local and remote connections, click the appropriate protocol to enable for your environment, and then click Apply.

Note Click OK when you receive the following message:
Changes to Connection Settings will not take effect until you restart the Database Engine service.

On the Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections page, expand Database Engine, click Service, click Stop, wait until the MSSQLSERVER service stops, and then click Start to restart the MSSQLSERVER service.

Comment: 1. This is not SQL Server 2005; 2. Please attribute all copy/pastes. Here's one I found which was probably also copy pasted: https://sakafi.wordpress.com/2008/05/22/how-to-configure-sql-server-2005-to-allow-remote-connections/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps..

- The server is powered off
- Sqlserver is not running
- Sqlserver is running on a different port to the default
- Sqlserver is not configured to accept tcp connections (see tripuri's answer)
- An interim firewall, or windows firewall is blocking the connection
- There is an interim network failure between your machine and the server
- You're running it locally and your recent version of windows is prohibiting loopback connections

Answer (score 0):

The other answers seem to ignore the fact that this is on RDS. A couple of items to check.

1. Is the security group opened to allow traffic to the RDS instance?
2. Where is the client that you're trying to connect from?
3. Have you ever been able to connect to it?
4. Please provide details of your network and VPC configuration.

I suspect the issue is in the security group and/or issues with the VPC configuration.